# Magento 2, 404 Not Found, nginx issue

Tags: magento2, error, nginx

I am trying to access files from the root folder by the url like:

 `localhost/magento2.2.2/testfolder/test.php`


and I can do it fine on my test server but in my company **nginx** forbids me from accessing any file.

Should I edit `nginx.conf.sample` or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

The root of Magento 2 is the `http/pub/`.

Try to add a NginX configuration similar to this one:

```
# test.php
location = /magento2.2.2/testfolder/test.php {
    alias /full/path/to/the/file/test.php;
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need the equal sign but it didn't work